# get confuse when call primary constructor in scala

Tags: scala, oop

I am learning the scala and I have try with the following code.

```
object Demo7 {
        def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
                class Person(val fullName: String) {
                        println(s"This is the primary constructor. Name is ${fullName}")
                        val initial = fullName.substring(0, 1) // Computed during initialization

                        //def this(firstName: String, lastName: String) = this(s"$firstName $lastName")

                }
                new Person("Tek Tuk")
                new Person("Tek Tuk").fullName 

        }
}
```

then I run I get the same returned  result as each call.
for my understanding this line

```
new Person("Tek Tuk").fullName
```

Shouldn't compile, anyone can explain me why this line get compile and return the same result as the first line?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please write a question as a full sentence?

Comment: Why do you think the second line should result in an error?

Comment: What error you get? What behavior you expect?

Comment: Why do you think your second example shouldn't compile?

Comment: yes because I see `fullName` is not declare as property it is only the parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're asking why you're allowed to access the `fullName` field of your `Person` class, that's because you've declared it as a `val` in the parameter list.

This is the same as declaring it a `public final` field in Java. If you want it to be private, just remove the `val` part, i.e.

```
class Person(fullName: String) {
  (...)
}
```

As for why both calls "return" the same thing - they don't.

- `new Person("Tek Tuk")` returns an instance of `Person`.
- `new Person("Tek Tuk").fullName` returns `"Tek Tuk"` - a `String`. You created another instance of `Person` with the same `fullName` and you called `fullName` on it.

Both, however, print `"This is the primary constructor. Name is Tek Tuk"`, because you called the same constructor in both cases and you have a `println` that prints this in the constructor.

Comment: A minor quibble with "This is the same as declaring it a public final field in Java". It is actually a private field with a public getter method.